# What's the best way to format ACF number fields for display on the front end?

Tags: php, javascript

I hired someone to help with this, and he had a javascript solution which he entered in the theme footer. I just added an html tag and it worked.
However, it broke because he didn't use the child theme. I tried copying the footer.php file into the child theme and re-adding his script, but it didn't work. Here is the code.

```
    <script>

 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 // Your code in here

 $( ".priceToFormat" ).each(function( ) {
 $(this).formatCurrency();
 }
 );

 $( ".numberToFormat" ).each(function( ) {
 $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
 //$(this).toNumber();
 }
 );

 });

 </script>
```

I need to format both number and money, so thousands separators, decimals, etc. I am using Beaver Themer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the wp_footer action hook, similar to this

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_my_script'); 
function add_my_script() {
?>
<script>
// your script code here
</script>
<?php
return;
}
```

This hook will hook into the themes' `wp_footer()` call, so it will happen as part of the theme's display of the footer.

Place this code in the functions.php file of your Child Theme.

Read more about how the footer is displayed, and how you can modify it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer

**Added**

Here's is your script code inserted into my example. Syntax checks OK; I have not checked for desired operation.

```
 add_action('wp_footer', 'add_my_script'); 

function add_my_script() {
?>

<script>

 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 // Your code in here

 $( ".priceToFormat" ).each(function( ) {
 $(this).formatCurrency();
 }
 );

 $( ".numberToFormat" ).each(function( ) {
 $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
 //$(this).toNumber();
 }
 );

 });

 </script>

<?php
return;
}
```

(Not sure why a downvote on my original answer.)

Comment: I appreciate your help. I put it together and tested and am getting a syntax error line 5

     `add_action('wp_footer', 'add_my_script'); 
     function add_my_script() {
     ?>
     <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
     ( ".priceToFormat" ).each(function( ) {
     $(this).formatCurrency();
     }
     );

     $( ".numberToFormat" ).each(function( ) {
     $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
     //$(this).toNumber();
     }
     );

     });
     </script>
     <?php
     return;
     }`

Sorry for formatting

Comment: A quick look at your code (after I formatted it within my editor - there are online formatters for JS) it looks like you have some unbalanced parenthesis in the JS code. Try running your code through an on-line formatter (ask the googles) and make corrections as needed. Everything within the <script> tags needs to be valid for things to work.
Your original code in your question is valid syntax, so it looks like you missed something when you copy/pasted into the function.

Comment: See added info in my answer - your script properly 'balanced' - it passes a syntax check.

Comment: I appreciate your help! Unfortunately this solution didn't seem to work with Beaver Themer. It blocks everything from loading.

Comment: Look for console errors in Developer Tools (F12). Lots of times that will help with JS errors.